# Problems with integrating piece-wise function

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm  lost in integrating two types of piece-wise function

Type-1:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}a & \text{if }x\text{ even}\\b &\text{if }x\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ on interval $[0,9]$

Type-2:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x=1\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ on interval $[1,\infty)$

Can anyone direct me about how to solve these types of function? I'm specially unsure about the limits of the integrals.

I've done the common types such as

$f(x)=\begin{cases}a & \text{if }x<0\\b &\text{if }x\geq0\end{cases}$ on interval $[-9,9]$

Comment: $x$ is even or odd is only making sense if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: You probably want an expression for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^x f(k)$, right ?

Comment: to integrate over a domain, the variable has to be continuous which is not the same here. I think what @callculus has said makes more sense as a question but correct be if I'm wrong

Comment: I succeeded to solve this one. x acts as discrete random variable here which wasn't mentioned actually in the source of my question. And yes @callculus you're right. It is solved using Riemann Sum. Thanks everyone ❤

Comment: @SajibIglesias You´re welcome.